# JAVASCRIPT autocomplete text input value by variable made from excel cell's data | cross-browser | no ActiveXobject

Tags: javascript

The situation looks like this - I need to retrieve data from specific excel cells and put it in online form automatically. This is not my website so I have to do this in browser. ActiveX is not an option from security reasons and cross-browser problems.

1. I have an excel file from the client with multiple sheets and different values on them (Purchase Order).
2. Every time excel looks the same and it always has the same number of cells - only data changes.
3. There are sheets which represent the products  - for ex. there is a list of 100 products (100 rows)
4. When client puts a number in "quantity" column of the specific product(row) the product code appears in the neighbour column.
5. So table is filled in partially - the rest of the rows is left with "0" in quantity column and with "none" in product code column.

I want to "crawl" this excel to get this product codes together with quantities (i will use 'for' loop and 'if' function - no problem). Then (i guess) I'll put data into array and use it to put 'product code' in one input, 'quantity' in second input, then click "save and add another item" and at the last item click "save&close" instead.

And the problem is I could not find anything else from ActiveX. I do not have problem in writing 'for' loops or other functions. My problem is how to 'call' the excel file and specific cell and read it's value and put it into variable.

I completely do not understand JSON concept - maybe I should?

Second problem is how to run my script on client's website through browser.
The rest is easy - I will use querySelector to click buttons, document.getElementById to fill inputs, etc.

Thank You in advance,
Arek

Comment: You can use [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) it will read the excel file and return array of objects you, here is one example how it works

```js
$("#excelFile").change(function (event) {
    alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:false})', [event.originalEvent], function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@0.5"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.1/xlsx.core.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<input type="file" id="excelFile" />
```